# How to delete 4 spaces (1 indent) at once in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython, auto-indent

I am using IPython in my terminal. It auto-indents with 4 spaces. Sometimes, I need to delete 1 indent. Using the backspace deletes 1 space at a time. I have tried various key combinations to achieve the deletion of 1 indent, but I was not able to do it.

Is there any configuration option that would achieve the intended behavior?

EDIT: I have tried the following: shift+tab, ctrl+tab, alt+tab, shift+backspace, ctrl+backspace, alt+backspace, ctrl + ], etc.

Comment: No idea why this is so downvoted.  I have the exact same issue, and this post describes it clearly.  Can you perhaps post the link to your github issue here in the comments?

Comment: I have moved on from IPython. Currently, I use [xonsh](https://xon.sh/). This is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12542).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ctrl+u` as long as you place your cursor behind the text, otherwise it will delete the text on the line

Comment: Thanks. `ctrl + u` works as you suggested. Does backspace work for others?

Comment: Backspace would work in a jupyter notebook and IDEs such as pycharm yes, if my answer solved your problem please remember to mark it as accepted

Comment: Well, It didn't solve my problem exactly. For example, if I want 2 indents and IPython gives me 3, I would have to press `ctrl+u`, `tab`, `tab` to achieve that.

Comment: Sorry I can't find any way to do that, I'm not sure unindenting is possible

Comment: Thank you for helping nonetheless. I got to learn about `ctrl+u`. I have also posted on IPython's github. Let's see if I can get anything from there.